# Fighting with images in E-mail

Tags: ios, image, email

My App sends an e-mail with images but there is no images in the e-mail.

I create a HTML string and send that as the body in the e-mail. But there is nothing in the e-mail when doing it on the device.
In the simulator is okay.
I put a WebView in my App and put the HTML in and its shows all the images.

Anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: Are you attaching the image?

Comment: Have you embedded the image in the email or are you linking to images?

Answer (score 0):

This is code I used to attach image in mail body

```
NSMutableString *htmlBody = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"<html><body>"];
    [htmlBody appendString:@"<p>Enter Text Here</p>"];
    UIImage *emailImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(emailImage)];
    NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedString];
    [htmlBody appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p><b><img src='data:image/png;base64,%@'>  </b></p>",base64String]];
    [htmlBody appendString:@"</body></html>"];
    NSLog(@"%@",htmlBody);
    [mailComposer htmlBody isHTML:YES];
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: Yes but you write image.png and I want the get an images from the documents directory. Does your code do that?

Comment: Its very simple, in my code, for emailImage which is UIImage, just fetch image from documents directory in similar way. For fetching image from document directory in form of UIImage, refer this link http://guerratopia.com/en/how-to-saveload-or-remove-images-in-iphoneipad-documents-directory

Comment: I have been out of the office so I have not tried it yet. But somebody else told me that I cannot put references to images on my device into some HTML code. But I will try your code very soon.

Comment: I get an error in this line: NSString *base64String = [imageData base64EncodedString];

Comment: You need to have base64EncodedString, search over google you will find its extension class